How to find what programs are using an external SSD?
After buying a Samsung Portable SSD T7 shield I connected it to my Asus computer (running Windows 10) and then opened a setup file and followed the steps to install and put a password on the drive. After doing that I deleted the setup files on the drive and attempted to eject it, which gave me this message.

"This Device is currently in use. Close any programs or windows that might be using the device, and then try again"

I spent a few hours trying figure out what was wrong, and then more time closing or deleting files and programs that seemed like they could be an issue.
I'm still not sure what is preventing me from ejecting the Drive and would appreciate any help with the following:

How to find programs running on or using the drive?
Any method to locate programs running on or using the drive?
How to safely eject the drive?

I haven't put any files on the drive yet so If a solution requires me to start from scratch that's fine, I just want to understand what's happening and how to prevent it.
Edit:
I made things worse
Yesterday I purchased a samsung SSD while trying to instal the program that came on the drive (I dont remember the exact name but it was similar toSamsungPortableSSD_1.0.exe) after setting a password I felt satisfied and went to transfer the drive to a diffrent laptop to begin storing files on it. When I tried to safley extract the drive I realized I couldnt find anywhere to extract the drive, leading me to make the original post.
Today things have gotten worse. At the start of the day I could see the drive under "This PC" the image of the drive had a fully red memory bar and any attempt to alter files, format the drive, and at times extract the drive led to an error message about the drive being set to write only. Assuming it would be a simple sollution I began trying to take off write only mode by following along with youtube turorials that attempted to clear write only mode though CMD ran as administator, and by creating a file in registry editor under the path "Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Storage Device Policies" as of writting, I canot find the drive anywhere in windows file exploer but its still visible in
disk managment.
Before my goal was to safly remove the SSD but it seems like thats not as big of an issue as I previously belived, and currenlty I can do that without issue, so now I have one  goal:
Turn off Read only on the SSD and if possible, make it visible in File explorer

Have you just disconnected the drive and checked to see what has happened? What software did you install from the drive? Drives usually don't REQUIRE software in order to work, and the first thing I'd suspect is whatever software you installed, and I'd look for any tool in that software to tell the drive it is ready for disconnect.

I was hesitant to unplug the Drive because I couldn't find anything about whether or not that could damage the drive. Upon disconnecting the drive it seems to be working fine. A bit embarrassing that the solution was that simple but Im glad you helped me solve it. Thank you music2myear.

The apps that normally stop a device from being ejected are Windows Explorer, virus checkers and windows defender.

You can find programs which are using the drive with Process Explorer from SysInternals package. There is option to find handles and DLLs.
But for you solution may be the same package (SysInternals) and progam Sync in it. If you run it sync64 -r you may write all caches to external drive and be able to disconnect it properly. Also please remember that any open Explorer window with this external drive is forbidding proper drive detachment.

Sometimes things just get hung up. Especially as you have not written any data to the drive (that you know about or care about) at this time, just disconnect the drive and see whether or not things work OK afterwards.
Another thing to check in this case is the software that you installed when you connected the drive. Drives do not usually require software in order to work in Windows, but some will come with "helpful" utilities that may offer encryption or other features. Find this software on your computer and see if it offers any helps for disconnecting the drive. Also, unless you know that you need the features of that software, you may consider simply removing it altogether.
